# How do you access the ui.item children in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom-traversal

I'm trying to access the following rectangularized item using the jQuery sortable plugin:
[image]

Currently my jQuery code looks like this (Note the question is about the even in the receive section):

```
$( "#listA, #listB" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected_sortable",
    delay: 100,
    receive: function(event, ui) {
                alert(ui.item.text());
            }
}).disableSelection();
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="listA" class="connected_sortable ui-sortable">
  <li>
    <div id="4">
    Test Text
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How would I access that id using the alert? I tried `alert(ui.item.context.childNodes.id)` and the alert returns an 'undefined'.

edits: added HTML and clarified the question abit.

Thank you!

Comment: You should post the HTML code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
alert(ui.item.context.childNodes[0].id)
```

Comment: That's not working in 2013. Here's what does work: alert(ui.item[0].id)

Answer (score 0):

You can access id of an element with `.attr`

```
var id = $("yourSelector").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

try `alert('ui.item >li').attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/a8bNn/1/

- Using "update" instead of "receive"
- use "ui.item.context.childNodes[1].id" to grab the id